# How to find out next character alphabetically?

Tags: c#, char

How we can find out the next character of the entered one. For example, if I entered the character "b" then how do I get the answer "c"?

Comment: What is the answer if I enter "ñ"? And "ç"? And "1"? And "."? (Related question: Are there any restrictions in the input?)

Comment: This is one of those "don't assume it works the same in other countries" kind of things I think. Something that gives you the expected result for file names might not be what somebody from Turkey or China would find easy to read.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this:

```
char letter = 'c';

if (letter == 'z')
    nextChar = 'a';
else if (letter == 'Z')
    nextChar = 'A';

else
    nextChar = (char)(((int)letter) + 1);
```

This way you have no trouble when the char is the last of the alphabet.

Comment: Wait - replace the '+ 1' with '+ 13' and you get...?

Comment: Note that you can write `(char)(letter + 1)` instead

Answer (score 25):

How about:

```
char first = 'c';
char nextChar = (char)((int) first + 1);
```

Comment: what does that return for 'z'?

Comment: That will surely NOT work. I was trying to be simplistic by not adding validation code. But seeing the comments to question, I think I shouldn't have answered. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: if first char = 'z', this code will give the next char which is '{', thus not in the alphabet.

Comment: nah, enough variation and discussion of answers will give the asker the desired exercise of thinking the question through

Comment: IT returns the next value from ascii table (http://www.asciitable.com/) . Of course you could also add a simple: if (nextchar > 'z') nextChar = 'a'; (adding more logic (ie Capitalized letters) is also very simple)

Comment: Well, he accepted the answer, so it probably works for him :)

Comment: Let's hope you're not using EBDIC encoding.

Comment: Short and sweet.  If necessary add some guard code like David suggested, but still short and sweet.  This is also the most common approach in many other languages.

Answer (score 11):

Note that a char will implicitly cast to an int. Here's a simplified solution:

```
char incrementCharacter(char input)
{
    return (input == 'z'? 'a': (char)(input + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the simplest way is a little function and an array of the 26 chars.  Then you can decide what you want to return for 'z'.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the character to a number, increment the number and then convert back.

But consider what will happen for "z" or "á" (Latin Small Leter A with Acute).

Answer (score 1):

This Change value useful for Excel application to find previous column

```
public static string PrevExecelColumn( string s)
    {
        s = s.ToUpper();
        char[] ac = s.ToCharArray();
        int ln = ac.Length;
        for (int i = ln - 1; i > -1; i--)
        {
            char c = ac[i];

            if (c == 'A')
            {
                ac[i] = 'Z';
                continue;
            }

            ac[i] = (char)(((int)ac[i]) - 1);
            break;

        }
        s = new string(ac);
        return s;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public string GetNextAlphabetLetter(int indice) {
  return ((char)('A' + indice)).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

need to just add 1 in character you get next character.
It works on ASCII values.