# Good way to refactor this/reduce LOC?

Tags: c#, refactoring, character, switch-statement

I have this code:

```
switch (currentLetter)
{
    case 'A': return 'B';
    case 'B': return 'C';
    case 'C': return 'D';
    case 'D': return 'E';
    case 'E': return 'F';
    case 'F': return 'G';
    case 'G': return 'H';

    case 'a': return 'b';
    case 'b': return 'c';
    case 'c': return 'd';
    case 'd': return 'e';
    case 'e': return 'f';
    case 'f': return 'g';
    case 'g': return 'h';
}
```

I thought of many ways to change it but I'm not sure on which to choose. I could replace all the returns with `(char)(currentLetter + 1)`, use if statements with ASCII values to determine range and then do `(char)(currentLetter + 1)`, use `Enumerable.Range.Contains` and then see if the value is within the range, replace the switch with an if, etc.

This code will not be repeated anywhere else and I'm not sure if this isn't the best way of doing it since it's very clear to the reader of the code to what's going on and they don't have to think of character codes, arithmetic, etc. Also, there will never be any more characters to add to the case statements so it won't get unwieldy.

Not sure if I should leave it as is or change it.

Comment: It's a little verbose, but it is clear.  If it's used only in one place, I'd leave it as is.  You'll probably spend more time to reduce the LOC (and possibly reduce maintainability/readability) than the LOC savings would be worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
return (char)(currentLetter + 1);
```

If you need to perform a range test

```
if ("ABCDEFGabcdefg".Contains(currentLetter)) {
    return (char)(currentLetter + 1);
}
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
    "Letter in the range 'A'-'G' or 'a'-'g' expected.");
```

It is visible immediately, that the next letter in the alphabet is returned without inspecting a long list of cases. Also it's less prone to errors.

---

UPDATE: `char` is considered to be a numeric type in C# and can implicitly be converted to other numeric types that are at least 16 bit wide. You can even apply the increment and decrement operators on them. Therefore a shorter solution with no casting exists:

```
return ++currentLetter;
```

Note: This changes the original value of `currentLetter`, but since `char` is not a reference type, this should not be a problem, if `currentLetter` was a method parameter. Also, the pre-increment operator must be used, as the old value would be returned with the post-increment operator!

Comment: As in the other SO thread ... what happens when the currentLetter is 'z'?

Answer (score 5):

Leave it.

Code clarity in a non-performance oriented section of code that won't be copy/pasted throughout your code base is typically preferable to 'elegant' solutions when there may be anyone else that may end up having to maintain it (or yourself trying to remember what you were doing) later on.

If you're looking for an iterator type of function - there's one on SO here: [How to find out next character alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026220/how-to-find-out-next-character-alphabetically)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Maybe there's a difference between optimization and aesthetics (depending on definition of optimize). I think the Original Poster is clearly aware it doesn't change the performance of his code [significantly], but maybe he had a feeling it didn't look nice.

Comment: Looked fine to me, I could read and understand it, which means it's head and shoulders above a lot of the code I've seen. It meets every aesthetic need I have, I'd marry it if I could afford a divorce. Over my career I've become intensely suspicious of changing working code to look nicer. Most times proponents of this principle are in the clever enough to be really dangerous category.

Comment: @Tony ... I agree on the refactoring of working code, but Olivier's solution is straightforward and legible as well given the index bounding as an implementation if this is new code. The old SO answer I linked provides the fix if the letters need to wrap (z=>a) so that'd work nice too. I should have asked if the stop at 'g' was the end of the sequence or if it did include all alpha characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use ASCII codes and a descriptive method name so it's clear to future developers. Turn it into an extension method even. Even though you have no current plans to change or use this somewhere else doesn't mean you won't in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of taste. How about:

```
if (currentLetter >= 'A' && currentLetter <= 'G'
  || currentLetter >= 'a' && currentLetter <= 'g')
{
  ++currentLetter;
  return currentLetter;
}
```

This assumes `currentLetter` is a *local* variable (which has not been caught by an anonymous function which is referenced outside the current method) because I increment it.