# Add next character to each char in a string

Tags: c#, string

i've to return it with the next character in the ASCII table, example:

```
string tmp = "hello";
string modified = "ifmmp";
```

I've tried to split string into characters and sum 1 to each character but it gives out an error.

Comment: can you show which error are you facing

Comment: hint use toCharArray() then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026220/how-to-find-out-next-character-alphabetically then concat

Comment: When asking a question you should show us your code and be precise about the error. As it is there is absolutely no way we can tell you what is wrong because, well, we can't see your code. Even if you told us what the error was we might be able to guess from that what your code is and where it is going wrong. As it is though this question isn't helpfully answerable (and we try not to just write code for people on request).

Comment: There are several hard and soft boundaries for this type of character transformation. If your allowable data won't contain certain [UTF-16 code units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B0000_to_U.2BD7FF_and_U.2BE000_to_U.2BFFFF), you could keep your algorithm simple and guard it with something like  `if (c >= '\uD7FF') throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
public string NextCharString(string str)
{
    string result = "";
    foreach(var c in str)
    {
        if (c=='z') result += 'a';
        else if (c == 'Z') result += 'A';
        else result += (char)(((int)c) + 1)
    }
}
```

Edit: I assumed adding one to all characters is cyclic, that is, adding one to 'z' will give an 'a'

Comment: Thank you mate, this is exactly what I was searching for

Comment: There seems to be some kind of presumption of an alphabet for a writing system for a language in your wrapping. English, perhaps.

Comment: `char` can be implicitly cast to an `int` so you can do `c + 1` to remove an extra cast.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
            string tmp = "hello";
            string modified = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
            {
                char c = getNextChar(tmp[i]);
                modified += c;
            }

         // 'modified' will be your desired output
```

Create this method  :

```
       private static char getNextChar(char c)
        {

            // convert char to ascii
            int ascii = (int)c;
            // get the next ascii
            int nextAscii = ascii + 1;
            // convert ascii to char
            char nextChar = (char)nextAscii;
            return nextChar;
        }
```

Comment: Mentioning the "ASCII" encoding is a bit misleading here. `char` is a UTF-16 code unit, which is one of several encodings for the Unicode character set.